# Nuget Issue : Building a nuget with netstandard2.1 as TargetFramework doesnt list compile time dependencies for netstandard2.0 project

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard-2.0, .net-standard-2.1

Scenario

1. There is a nuget built with TargetFramework set to 2.1
2. There are multiple projects some with netstandard2.1 and some with netstandard2.0 as part of nuget compilation.
3. nuspec file of the nuget contains all projects of both netstandard2.1 and 2.0 as projectreference.

Problem :
Once the nuget project is compiled, assemblies with netstandard2.0 are not listed as compile time dependencies, only netstandard2.1 are consumable and listed, when the nuget is consumed in any of the netcore projects.

Ask : We want the nuget to load netstandard2.0 as compile time dependencies.